Why spark Created 4 jobs and 6 stages for the following pyspark code
I am new to spark coding, I am trying to understand the SPARK UI, I am using the follwing code. I am confused on number of jobs and tasks created by spark.
Code:
    sc = SparkContext()
    glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
    spark = glueContext.spark_session
    job = Job(glueContext)

    _schema = "InvoiceID string, Branch string, City string, CustomerType string, Gender string, \
               ProductLine string, UnitPrice double, Quantity integer, Tax_5 double, Total double, \
               Date date, Time timestamp, Payment string, CustomeID string"

    df = spark.read.format("csv").schema(_schema) \
            .option("header", True) \
            .option("sep", ",") \
            .load("s3://*******************/test/sales/")
            
    # df = df.repartition("City", "Branch", "ProductLine")

    df = df.where("CustomerType = 'Member'")

    df1 = df.groupBy("City", "Branch", "ProductLine").agg(
        sum(col("Quantity")).alias("total_quantity"),
        avg(col("UnitPrice")).alias("avg_unit_price")
    )

    df1 = df1.where("Branch in ('A','B')").withColumn("avg_unit_price", col("avg_unit_price")-100)

    df1.explain(mode="formatted")
    df1.show()

    df2 = df.groupBy("City", "Branch").agg(
        sum(col("Quantity")).alias("total_quantity"),
        avg(col("UnitPrice")).alias("avg_unit_price")
    )

    df2 = df2.where("Branch in ('A')").withColumn("avg_unit_price", col("avg_unit_price")-10)
    df2.explain(mode="formatted")
    df2.show()

There are only 2 actions in code(2 .show() functions), hence there should be 2 jobs. And as there are 2 suffles(2 group by aggregations) so there should be 4 stages. Please correct me if I am wrong. I have attached the spark UI screenshot.



actions -> 1 load + 1 headers + 1 show + 1 show = 4 jobs

@s.polam could you please give little bit more context. I see some jobs are skipped also some stages are skipped. I see the data sufle happening in 1st job, is that OK, because the suffle should have happened in 2nd job

add explain(true) output in your question
